# How to get ContainerView with embedded UITableView to update height constraint as number of tableView cells changes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a ContainerView with an embedded UITableView. As the number of rows in the table increases I want the ContainerView height to increase. I have tried using preferredContentSizeDidChange but this is having no effect. I am not sure actually how this notification is working. How does the TableView make this work? Is there a way to do this?

```
class HomeVC: ContentViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var containerHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer) {

    self.containerHeight.constant = container.preferredContentSize.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I added this function to the embedded TableViewController class which is called every time the table data is updated. It relies on the rowHeight to be stated here as well as in heightForRowAt which doesn't seem right, but it works!

```
func adjustRowHeight() {
    let rowHeight = CGFloat(100)
    print("rowHeight is \(rowHeight)")
    let newRowHeight = CGFloat(bLEManager.discoveredPeripherals.count) * rowHeight
    print("newRowHeight is \(newRowHeight)")
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width, height: newRowHeight)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```